# Pull back of twisted sheaf under a regular map associated to a base point free linear system

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, sheaf-theory, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Let $D$ be a divisor on a normal projective variety $X$ and $V$ be a subspace of the global section of $\mathscr O_X(D),$ L is a base point free linear system and $\phi_L:X\overset{(g_0:\cdots:g_n)}\longrightarrow \mathbb P^n$ the regular map associated to L.

I have to show

**$\phi^*_L(\mathscr O_{\mathbb P^n}(m))\cong O_X(mD)$** for all $m\in\mathbb Z.$

PS. I thought about it and I have the following idea.

Let $E=1.Z(x_0)$ be the divisor in $\mathbb P^n.$ Then $\mathscr O_{P^n}(E)|_{U_i}=(X_i/X_0)\mathscr O_{U_i}$ where $U_i=\{x_i\neq 0\}.$ Then I know there exists a divisor $\tilde E$ in $X$ such that $\mathscr O_{X}(\tilde E)|_{V_i}=(g_i/g_0)\mathscr O_{X}|{V_i}$ where $V_i=\phi_L^{-1}(U_i).$

I do not understand how to relate $O_{X}(\tilde E)$ with $O_{X}(D)$

Any kind of hint or suggestion will be extremely helpful.

Comment: Can you prove, denoting by $H$ the hyperplane section of $\mathbb{P}^n$, $\phi^*(mH)=m\phi^*(H)$?

Comment: Suppose $H=Z(f)$. Now $m\phi^*(H)=m\phi^*(div~f)=\phi^*(m ~div~f)=\phi^*(mH)$

Comment: Doesn't it prove what you need?

Comment: Could you please provide a little detail. As I am studying the these for the first time, I am not quite comfortable going back and forth between sheaf and divisor.

Comment: @Cusp it might be helpful to know what book/notes you're using as a primary reference.

Comment: @TabesBridges I am reading from Shafarevich. Although I saw this exercise online.

Comment: @Cusp I see; this is the sort of thing that is a bit tricky to help with because of differences in order of presentation and the like. Do you understand that $D$ should be thought of as a hyperplane section $X \cap H$ of $X \subset \mathbb P^n$, and how $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^n}(H) \cong \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^n}(1)$, where the left hand side refers to the "twisting a sheaf by a Cartier divisor" construction while the right hand side is the Serre twisting sheaf?

Comment: @TabesBridges I think $\mathscr O_{\mathbb P^n}(1)=\mathscr O_{\mathbb P^n}(Z(x_0)).$ I have edited the question and added my thought about it. It will be really helpful if you can give some further ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Let $Z(x_0)$ be a divisor of $\mathbb{P}^n$. Then a section $s\in \phi^*_L(O_{\mathbb{P}^n}(mZ(x_0)))$ has the property that for each couple of  open neighborhoods $(\phi_L^*)^{-1}(U_i)$ and  $(\phi_L^*)^{-1}(U_j)$ we have

$s_i=(\frac{(x_0)_i}{(x_0)_j})^m\circ \phi_Ls_j=\frac{(x_0)_i^m\circ \phi_L}{(x_0)_j^m\circ \phi_L}s_j=(\frac{g_{0i}}{g_{0j}})^ms_j=g_{ij}^ms_j$

where $g_0$ is a global section of $D$ and the first component of the map $\phi_L$ while $g_{ij}$ is the cocycle of the divisor $D$. Then $g_{ij}^m$ is the cocycle of the divisor $mD$ so you have that $s$ is a section of the divisor $mD$, that it  means $s\in O_X(mD)$